# Plus jaloux que moi, tu meurs

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions

I encountered this sentence I cannot understand. Does it have any connection with "c'est plus fort que moi"? Thanks for any input.

> Cet hôpital est rempli de jolies infirmières. Plus jaloux que moi, tu meurs.

Answer (score 10):

No, it does not have anything to do with the expression "c'est plus fort que moi". You can see it as a conditional statement:

> Plus jaloux que moi, tu meurs.
>
> = (Si tu **étais**) plus jaloux que moi, tu **mourrais**.

It's a hyperbolic, jocular expression, meaning that the speaker is as jealous of the situation as they come -- to such an extent that an even higher level of jealousy (if at all possible) could be fatal. You can place virtually any adjective of your choice:

> Plus + {*adjective*} + que moi, tu meurs.

Answer (score 7):

It is a French idiom:

> *Plus* adjective *que* noun/pronoun, *tu meurs*.

It originates from a French variant spoken in Northern Africa ([pataouète](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pataou%C3%A8te)) until 1962 and was later popularized in metropolitan France slang. It is recorded *Dictionnaire du français argotique et populaire*, François Caradec, 1977. It was likely imported by Italian speaking immigrants to Algeria because the following expression is well known since at least the beginning of the 20th century.:

> *Più xxx di cosi, si muore* (more xxx than that, people die)

It means, of course figuratively: if you manage to be more xxx than yyy, you die (because you have exceeded what is humanly possible.)

Here, nobody can be more jealous than the person speaking.

There is a also this famous pun from *[Pierre Desproges](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Desproges)*, a great French humorist:

> Plus cancéreux que moi, tumeur.

On the other hand, *c'est plus fort que moi* is another French idiom which is unrelated to the former. It means *I can't resist / I can't help xxx*.

Comment: It got me thinking: you usually use a masculine adjective by default in this expression, but what's your take on "*Plus **belle** que moi, tu meurs !*"? Even in conversation among women, I wonder if it is better to stick to "*Plus **beau** que moi, tu meurs !*"?

Comment: @Alone-zee A woman can't say *plus beau que moi, tu meurs* to another woman (agreement mismatch), and would avoid that idiom when talking to a man outside maybe the colloquial *plus beau que moi je suis belle, tu meurs*. For less "gender marked" adjectives like *grand*, that would be less of an issue. A woman might say to a man *plus grand que moi, tu meurs*. Of course, when the adjective is *épicène*, this problem doesn't exist: *plus bête que moi, tu meurs*.

Answer (score 4):

Excusez-moi de répondre en français. Je voulais juste préciser que cette expression est bien datée : elle vient du titre d'un film sorti en France en 1982 « [Plus beau que moi tu meurs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0211574/) » qui a connu une extraordinaire popularité.
La phrase est typique du vocabulaire d'Aldo Maccione, le caricatural playboy italien. Elle est impossible à traduire sans un idiomatisme de la langue de destination. Peut-être quelque chose comme "*It's impossible to be more xxx than me.*" Elle est en général utilisée avec ironie ou dérision.

Comment: L'expression est bien plus ancienne. Elle était utilisée par les Pied-Noirs en Algérie.

Comment: Merci. Intéressant, mais elle restait sans doute confinée : une recherche Ngram (sur "que moi tu meurs") ne la fait ressortir qu'avec le film. Étrange destinée de certaines expressions…

Comment: Je la connaissais avant la sortie du film, Ngram la trouve en 1975 (ou plutôt 1977). L'origine probable est italienne et date au moins du début du XXe siècle. Aldo Maccione a peut-être directement transcrit l'italien en français, indépendamment du pataouète.